# Cannot get very simple boolean check to update correctly, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, boolean, record

Having a very simple controller action to change the status of a boolean called "draft"

```
@interview.draft = true if @interview.draft == false

@interview.draft = false if @interview.draft == true

@interview.save!
```

Still this fails, In model I have no action that change the boolean, it will just not save the state correctly. Any idea why this happens?

Im using postgres and rails 4, i have it set to default to false in the migration and preventing null value for the draft column.

Comment: This will always return false as it will always be true when it reaches the second line. What is it supposed to do? If you just want to flip the value you could use `@interview.draft = !@interview.draft`

Comment: do you get any errors on your `@interview` instance? or any other errors at all?

Comment: you could also use `toggle!` for that. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/toggle!

Comment: @EgonWilzer I'm pretty sure you've answered it. Why answer in a comment? Now there'll be no "answer" for the OP to accept, and you wont get as many points.

Comment: You may also use `toggle` (without the bang(!)) if you want to assign `draft` values first before saving, as `toggle!` (with bang) automatically updates/saves the `@interview` record immediately in the database.

Answer (score 4):

Your action will always return false for `@interview.draft`, as it will always be true, when it reaches the second line.

If you just want to flip the value you could use

`@interview.draft = !@interview.draft`

or

`@interview.draft.toggle!`

as mentioned by xlembouras.

Answer (score 0):

Change below two lines :

```
@interview.draft = true if @interview.draft == false

@interview.draft = false if @interview.draft == true
```

You can do it many ways :

```
@interview.draft = @interview.draft ? false : true

@interview.draft = !@interview.draft

@interview.draft.toggle!
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple answer, it will behave like a **NOT** operator.

```
@interview.draft = !@interview.draft
@interview.save
```

This will generate your expected outcome. ;) 
Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

simple way

```
@interview.draft = !@interview.draft
```

or

```
@interview.draft = @interview.draft.! 

@interview.save
```